# Procrun cannot find the Registry key for service

Tags: java, batch-file, procrun

I'm trying to get my program to be a service so I found procrun from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html but I made a installService.bat and keep recieving the same error message when I try to run

```
./prunsrv.exe //TS//InkEstService
```

The error code is this

```
[2016-06-15 09:44:06] [warn]  [ 7136] The system cannot find the Registry key for service 'InkEstService'
[2016-06-15 09:44:06] [error] [ 7136] Load configuration failed
[2016-06-15 09:44:06] [error] [ 7136] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2016-06-15 09:44:06] [error] [ 7136] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 2 (Failed to load configuration)
[2016-06-15 09:44:06] [error] [ 7136] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

my installService.bat is as follows

```
set SERVICE_NAME=InkEstService
set PR_INSTALL=C:\Users\TStraley\Desktop\commons-daemon\prunsrv.exe

REM Service log configuration
set PR_LOGPREFIX=%SERVICE_NAME%
set PR_LOGPATH=c:\logs
set PR_STDOUTPUT=auto
set PR_STDERROR=auto
set PR_LOGLEVEL=Error

REM Path to java installation
set PR_JVM=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
set PR_CLASSPATH=C:\Users\TStraley\Desktop\Ink/Estimator\InkDataCollection.jar

REM Startup configuration
set PR_STARTUP=auto
set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STARTCLASS=Platform.Platform
set PR_STARTMETHOD=start

REM Shutdown configuration
set PR_STOPMODE=jvm
set PR_STOPCLASS=Platform.Platform
set PR_STOPMETHOD=stop

REM JVM configuration
set PR_JVMMS=256
set PR_JVMMX=1024
set PR_JVMSS=4000

REM Install service 
prunsrv.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%
```

I've been following the tutorial provided on https://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/build-windows-service-from-java-application-with-procrun/ ... any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also if I only try to run ./prunsrv.exe the same error message pops up except with "The system cannot find the Registry key for service 'prunsrv'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the prunsrv.exe to the name same as your service i.e "InkDataCollection.exe"

I have tried this it works for me.